# Directional arrow from source to destination driving directions

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, driving-directions

What I want : 
My app requires plotting driving directions from source to destination, which is done.My problem is I need a directional arrow pointing from source to destination.

What have I done:
I am able to draw an arrow, also I have calculated angle but don't know how to apply that angle to the code so that the arrow rotates... I have tried all code..nothing works,the arrow gets drawn at source but points in wrong direction.

PS: I have tried this [Direction between two GeoPoints in Google map in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6478564/840520) 
Didn't find solution 
I don't want to show google maps service.. I mean i don't want to use the `URI.parse()` thing.

Below is the code I am using :

```
  public class MapRouteActivity extends MapActivity {

    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    MapView mapView;
    private Road mRoad;
    public final double fromLat = 17.40531527709,
            fromLon = 78.46830368042, toLat = 17.42091669870207,
            toLon = 78.4507942199707;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String url = RoadProvider
                        .getUrl(fromLat, fromLon, toLat, toLon);
                InputStream is = getConnection(url);
                mRoad = RoadProvider.getRoute(is);
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
            textView.setText(mRoad.mName + " " + mRoad.mDescription);
            MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(mRoad, mapView);
            List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            listOfOverlays.clear();
            listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
            mapView.getController().setZoom(14);
            mapView.invalidate();
        };
    };

    private InputStream getConnection(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
            is = conn.getInputStream();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return is;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return true;
    }

    class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {
        Road mRoad;
        ArrayList<GeoPoint> mPoints;

        public MapOverlay(Road road, MapView mv) {
            mRoad = road;
            if (road.mRoute.length > 0) {
                mPoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
                for (int i = 0; i < road.mRoute.length; i++) {
                    mPoints.add(new GeoPoint(
                            (int) (road.mRoute[i][1] * 1000000),
                            (int) (road.mRoute[i][0] * 1000000)));
                }
                int moveToLat = (mPoints.get(0).getLatitudeE6() + (mPoints.get(
                        mPoints.size() - 1).getLatitudeE6() - mPoints.get(0)
                        .getLatitudeE6()) / 2);
                int moveToLong = (mPoints.get(0).getLongitudeE6() + (mPoints
                        .get(mPoints.size() - 1).getLongitudeE6() - mPoints
                        .get(0).getLongitudeE6()) / 2);
                GeoPoint moveTo = new GeoPoint(moveToLat, moveToLong);

                MapController mapController = mv.getController();
                mapController.animateTo(moveTo);
                mapController.setZoom(7);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mv, boolean shadow, long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mv, shadow);
            drawPath(mv, canvas);
            return true;
        }

        public void drawPath(MapView mv, Canvas canvas) {
            int x1 = -1, y1 = -1, x2 = -1, y2 = -1;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            for (int i = 0; i < mPoints.size(); i++) {
                Point point = new Point();
                mv.getProjection().toPixels(mPoints.get(i), point);
                x2 = point.x;
                y2 = point.y;
                if (i > 0) {
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
                }
                x1 = x2;
                y1 = y2;
            }


            Point pointFrom = new Point();
            GeoPoint gp1 = new GeoPoint((int) (fromLat * 1E6),
                    (int) (fromLon * 1E6));
            Point pointTo = new Point();
            GeoPoint gp2 = new GeoPoint((int) (toLat * 1E6),
                    (int) (toLon * 1E6));
            Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
            projection.toPixels(gp1, pointFrom);
            projection.toPixels(gp2, pointTo);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.arrow1);
            double dlon = gp2.getLongitudeE6() - gp1.getLongitudeE6();
            double dlat = gp2.getLatitudeE6() - gp1.getLatitudeE6();
            double angle = getDegrees(fromLat, fromLon, toLat, toLon, 15);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postTranslate(-25, -25);
            matrix.postRotate((float)Math.toRadians(angle));
            matrix.postTranslate(pointFrom.x, pointFrom.y);       
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);
        }
    }

    double getDegrees(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2, double headX) {

        double dLat =  Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double dLon =  Math.toRadians(long2-long1);

        lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        lat2 =  Math.toRadians(lat2);

        double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
        double x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) -
                Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);
        double brng = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));

        // fix negative degrees
        if(brng<0) {
            brng=360-Math.abs(brng);
        }

        return brng - headX;
    }
}
```

Code in Road.java

```
 public class Road {
    public String mName;
    public String mDescription;
    public int mColor;
    public int mWidth;
    public double[][] mRoute = new double[][] {};
    public Point[] mPoints = new Point[] {};
}
```

Code in Point.java

package com.abhi.maproute;

```
public class Point {
    String mName;
    String mDescription;
    String mIconUrl;
    double mLatitude;
    double mLongitude;
}
```

Code in RoadProvider.java

```
package com.abhi.maproute;

/**
 * @author asadafale
 *
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Stack;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class RoadProvider {

    public static Road getRoute(InputStream is) {
        KMLHandler handler = new KMLHandler();
        try {
            SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(is, handler);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return handler.mRoad;
    }

    public static String getUrl(double fromLat, double fromLon, double toLat,
            double toLon) {// connect to map web service
        StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
        urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en");
        urlString.append("&saddr=");// from
        urlString.append(Double.toString(fromLat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(fromLon));
        urlString.append("&daddr=");// to
        urlString.append(Double.toString(toLat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(toLon));
        urlString.append("&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
        System.out.println("url..."+urlString.toString());
        return urlString.toString();
    }
}

class KMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    Road mRoad;
    boolean isPlacemark;
    boolean isRoute;
    boolean isItemIcon;
    private Stack<String> mCurrentElement = new Stack<String>();
    private String mString;

    public KMLHandler() {
        mRoad = new Road();
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        mCurrentElement.push(localName);
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Placemark")) {
            isPlacemark = true;
            mRoad.mPoints = addPoint(mRoad.mPoints);
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("ItemIcon")) {
            if (isPlacemark)
                isItemIcon = true;
        }
        mString = new String();
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        String chars = new String(ch, start, length).trim();
        mString = mString.concat(chars);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {
        if (mString.length() > 0) {
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                if (isPlacemark) {
                    isRoute = mString.equalsIgnoreCase("Route");
                    if (!isRoute) {
                        mRoad.mPoints[mRoad.mPoints.length - 1].mName = mString;
                    }
                } else {
                    mRoad.mName = mString;
                }
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("color") && !isPlacemark) {
                mRoad.mColor = Integer.parseInt(mString, 16);
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("width") && !isPlacemark) {
                mRoad.mWidth = Integer.parseInt(mString);
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                if (isPlacemark) {
                    String description = cleanup(mString);
                    if (!isRoute)
                        mRoad.mPoints[mRoad.mPoints.length - 1].mDescription = description;
                    else
                        mRoad.mDescription = description;
                }
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("href")) {
                if (isItemIcon) {
                    mRoad.mPoints[mRoad.mPoints.length - 1].mIconUrl = mString;
                }
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("coordinates")) {
                if (isPlacemark) {
                    if (!isRoute) {
                        String[] xyParsed = split(mString, ",");
                        double lon = Double.parseDouble(xyParsed[0]);
                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(xyParsed[1]);
                        mRoad.mPoints[mRoad.mPoints.length - 1].mLatitude = lat;
                        mRoad.mPoints[mRoad.mPoints.length - 1].mLongitude = lon;
                    } else {
                        String[] coodrinatesParsed = split(mString, " ");
                        int lenNew = coodrinatesParsed.length;
                        int lenOld = mRoad.mRoute.length;
                        double[][] temp = new double[lenOld + lenNew][2];
                        for (int i = 0; i < lenOld; i++) {
                            temp[i] = mRoad.mRoute[i];
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < lenNew; i++) {
                            String[] xyParsed = split(coodrinatesParsed[i], ",");
                            for (int j = 0; j < 2 && j < xyParsed.length; j++)
                                temp[lenOld + i][j] = Double
                                        .parseDouble(xyParsed[j]);
                        }
                        mRoad.mRoute = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mCurrentElement.pop();
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Placemark")) {
            isPlacemark = false;
            if (isRoute)
                isRoute = false;
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("ItemIcon")) {
            if (isItemIcon)
                isItemIcon = false;
        }
    }

    private String cleanup(String value) {
        String remove = "<br/>";
        int index = value.indexOf(remove);
        if (index != -1)
            value = value.substring(0, index);
        remove = "&#160;";
        index = value.indexOf(remove);
        int len = remove.length();
        while (index != -1) {
            value = value.substring(0, index).concat(
                    value.substring(index + len, value.length()));
            index = value.indexOf(remove);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public Point[] addPoint(Point[] points) {
        Point[] result = new Point[points.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
            result[i] = points[i];
        result[points.length] = new Point();
        return result;
    }

    private static String[] split(String strString, String strDelimiter) {
        String[] strArray;
        int iOccurrences = 0;
        int iIndexOfInnerString = 0;
        int iIndexOfDelimiter = 0;
        int iCounter = 0;
        if (strString == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input string cannot be null.");
        }
        if (strDelimiter.length() <= 0 || strDelimiter == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Delimeter cannot be null or empty.");
        }
        if (strString.startsWith(strDelimiter)) {
            strString = strString.substring(strDelimiter.length());
        }
        if (!strString.endsWith(strDelimiter)) {
            strString += strDelimiter;
        }
        while ((iIndexOfDelimiter = strString.indexOf(strDelimiter,
                iIndexOfInnerString)) != -1) {
            iOccurrences += 1;
            iIndexOfInnerString = iIndexOfDelimiter + strDelimiter.length();
        }
        strArray = new String[iOccurrences];
        iIndexOfInnerString = 0;
        iIndexOfDelimiter = 0;
        while ((iIndexOfDelimiter = strString.indexOf(strDelimiter,
                iIndexOfInnerString)) != -1) {
            strArray[iCounter] = strString.substring(iIndexOfInnerString,
                    iIndexOfDelimiter);
            iIndexOfInnerString = iIndexOfDelimiter + strDelimiter.length();
            iCounter += 1;
        }

        return strArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: No answer...No comments...! :'(

Comment: What code is in the "Road" class??

Comment: Nothing crucial just to create an object with all details of the Road.I have posted code in edit.

Comment: Now not getting **RoadProvider** at RoadProvider.getUrl(fromLat, fromLon, toLat, toLon); and RoadProvider.getRoute(is);

Comment: The RoadProvider.java just gets the KML and parses it for plotting purpose.I doubt if it has anything to do with rotation of arrow.Everything works fine..except that the arrow drawn at source points in wrong direction and I have to make it pointing towards the destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new option (released at Google I/O 2012) is [symbols (including arrows) on polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PolylineSymbols), the directions renderer can create a polyline.