# Getting the entire Google maps web page source instead of just the generated KML file to parse

Tags: android, google-maps, sax, kml

I have developed an Android application that uses the Google maps and draws a route path from point A to B on the map. I have used the methods mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389995/directional-arrow-from-source-to-destination-driving-directions) post, and everything was working fine. Over the past days, I've tested the result on the emulator and on my phone, and the route path was successfully drawn.

However, without modifying literally ANYTHING in code, today I realized that the route path drawing fails and the app crashes. As I am expected to do, I use the following code to "build" the uri link for the KML file generation:

```
public static String getUrl(double fromLat, double fromLon, double toLat,
        double toLon) {// connect to map web service
    StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
    urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en");
    urlString.append("&saddr=");// from
    urlString.append(Double.toString(fromLat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(fromLon));
    urlString.append("&daddr=");// to
    urlString.append(Double.toString(toLat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(toLon));
    urlString.append("&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
    return urlString.toString();
}
```

This function returns a Uri like "**http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=35.5133804,24.0421933&daddr=35.511732,23.974715&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml**" for the kml file. However, after experimenting I realized that now with the exact same KML link as above, the SAX parser tries to parse **the entire Google maps web page source code**! When my app was working, I was downloading the generated kml file and parsed it successfully locally, which was of this form:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
    <Document>
    ...
    </Document>
</kml>
```

In contrast, now the downloaded file is the entire Google maps web page, which has the following form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type"/>   
        <meta content="Find local businesses, view maps and get driving directions in 
        Google Maps" name="description"/> <link href="//maps.gstatic.com/favicon.ico" 
        rel="shortcut icon"/>   
        <noscript> <meta content="0; URL=/m/directions?dirflg=&amp;saddr=35.5133804,24.0421933&amp;daddr=35.511732,23.974715&
        amp;hl=en&amp;oi=nojs" http-equiv="refresh"/> </noscript> <title>
        ...

tick('ua');var id = 'none';if (event.target){id =  
closestParentId(event.target);}else if (event.srcElement){
id = closestParentId(event.srcElement);}
var firstUserAction = event.type + '-' + id;
```

Of course this is the literal Google maps web page source that shows the route path when I view the page from my PC. So my question is if anyone experienced the same VERY weird problem that started happening just like this.

Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680872/google-maps-output-kml-broken

Comment: Thank you very much geocodezip! I've been spending the past days looking for posts at the SO website whether I was doing something wrong, but it never occurred to me that Google would have made changes just like that... REALLY ANNOYING!

Comment: You can see this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/11745316/1230123](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11745316/1230123)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have answered the original question mentioned above, but I don't have enough reputation points. So, I'll state it here:

A fast way that I did to migrate my app from using KML to JSON (and it seems to work up to now), is to follow [this](http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/routing-driving-directions-on-android-part-1-get-the-route/) post. As it is mentioned at the post, I changed the output from kml to dragdir and used the algorithm provided to decrypt the file that is downloaded from the Goole maps. This way I could get all the routing points and apply them to my app for further processing.

Hope this helps people who need a fast way to migrate their project.

Comment: This saved me from using the old Direction Api instead of the new Google Direction Api's [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#XML) Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Same here but I use the apis now as well:
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + startAdd+ "&destination=" + endAdd + "&sensor=true";

Comment: This saved me from using the old Direction Api instead of the new Google Direction Api's [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#XML) Thanks !